# Overlay percentage for barplot, while keeping count on the y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a bar plot with my independent variable on the x axis (Education level), and the count of my dependent variable on the y axis (Default on credit card debt).

`ggplot(cleancc, aes(x=factor(Education), fill = factor(DefaultOct05))) + geom_bar()`

[image]

I'd like to keep everything as is but simply show the percentages for each break in the bar.  For example, the blue part of the bar 2 is 23.7%.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have your dataset I cannot try it, but check out this option with stat_bin():

```
ggplot(cleancc, aes(x=factor(Education), fill = factor(DefaultOct05))) + 
geom_bar() +
stat_bin(geom = "text",
      aes(label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")),
      vjust = 5)
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.  But stat_bin() gave an error.  I used stat_count() instead.  The only issue is the percentages are on the total data set.  I'm looking to show the percentage of how each bar breaks down.  For example, (the blue and red should total to 100% for each bar).

Comment: As they already told you, your question is similar to the one in the page suggested in the link. Try the following way, adjusted from the linked page: `summary = cleancc %>% group_by(Education, DefaultOct05) %>%
  tally %>%
  group_by(Education) %>%
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n),
         n.pos = cumsum(n) - 0.5*n)

ggplot(summary, aes(x=Education, y=n, fill=DefaultOct05)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", pct*100),"%"), y=n.pos), 
            colour="white")`